# Need help with complex case statement SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select, case

I am unsure of the syntax for what I am trying to do. I need to select several address fields based on conditions.

The logic is solid but it seems the syntax is incorrect. It is giving me errors with 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case', 'Else', 'Else'.
The idea is to insert the address into the table if isprimary=1, if there is no primary insert the most recent address that isactive=1, if there is no active then insert the most recent address.

Please Help

---

-- Select One best address for Record 02

```
DECLARE @ygcaddress TABLE
(
[AccountID] varchar(10),
[Address1] varchar(25),
[City] varchar(22),
[State] varchar(3),
[Zip] varchar(9)
)
INSERT INTO @ygcaddress
CASE
WHEN Address.IsPrimary=1
THEN 
SELECT
LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
Address.City,
[Lookup].LookupValue,
Address.Zip
FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
WHERE Address.IsPrimary=1
ELSE
CASE
WHEN Address.IsActive=1
THEN
SELECT TOP 1
LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
Address.City,
[Lookup].LookupValue,
Address.Zip
FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
WHERE Address.IsActive=1
ELSE
SELECT TOP 1
LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
Address.City,
[Lookup].LookupValue,
Address.Zip
FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
END
END
```

Comment: Could you simplify the query without losing the essence of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Added parenthesis to case results, this should work (syntactically at least).

```
--Select One best address for Record 02 
DECLARE @ygcaddress TABLE ( [AccountID] varchar(10), [Address1] varchar(25), [City] varchar(22), [State] varchar(3), [Zip] varchar(9) ) 
INSERT INTO @ygcaddress 
SELECT 
CASE WHEN Address.IsPrimary=1 THEN 
    (
        SELECT LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25), Address.City, [Lookup].LookupValue, Address.Zip 
        FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID) INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID) INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID) INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID WHERE Address.IsPrimary=1 
    )
ELSE 
    CASE WHEN Address.IsActive=1 THEN 
        (SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25), Address.City, [Lookup].LookupValue, Address.Zip FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID) INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID) INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID) INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID WHERE Address.IsActive=1 )
    ELSE 
        (SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25), Address.City, [Lookup].LookupValue, Address.Zip FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID) INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID) INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID) INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID )
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, from what I can see it looks like a syntax error in your original question:

```
DECLARE @ygcaddress TABLE
(
    [AccountID] varchar(10),
    [Address1] varchar(25),
    [City] varchar(22),
    [State] varchar(3),
    [Zip] varchar(9)
)

INSERT INTO @ygcaddress
    CASE 

        WHEN Address.IsPrimary=1
        THEN 
        SELECT
        LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
        Address.City,
        [Lookup].LookupValue,
        Address.Zip
        FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
            INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
            WHERE Address.IsPrimary=1

        WHEN Address.IsActive=1
        THEN
        SELECT TOP 1
        LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
        Address.City,
        [Lookup].LookupValue,
        Address.Zip
        FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
            INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
            WHERE Address.IsActive=1

        ELSE
        SELECT TOP 1
        LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25),
        Address.City,
        [Lookup].LookupValue,
        Address.Zip
        FROM (((AccountPerson INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID)
            INNER JOIN @ygcaddress y ON Account.AccountID=y.AccountID)
            INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into this too much, you seem to be missing the "VALUES" keyword at the very least. The skeleton syntax for an INSERT statement is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

I'd suggest writing a correct INSERT statement with literal strings (or whatever) before you try to substitute anything more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly, I don't think you want a CASE statement at all: a CASE statement returns a value expression, not a tuple as you are trying to make it. (At least it does in SQL Server which is the SQL database I am most familar with)

EDITED to remove my first suggested solution using UNION, which I realised was incorrect.

EDITED again:

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO @ygcaddress 
SELECT
     Account.AccountID
    ,LEFT(Address.AddressLine1,25)
    ,Address.City
    ,[Lookup].LookupValue
    ,Address.Zip 
FROM AccountPerson 
INNER JOIN Account ON AccountPerson.AccountID=Account.AccountID
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
    A1.*
    CASE 
        WHEN A1.IsPrimary=1 THEN 10
        WHEN A1.IsPrimary=0 AND A1.IsActive=1 THEN 5
        ELSE 1
    END [Rank]
    FROM Address A1
    ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
) Address ON AccountPerson.PersonID=Address.PersonID 
INNER JOIN [Lookup] ON Address.StateID=[Lookup].LookupID
```